# Yii2 doesn't work yii2-poll-widget

Tags: yii2, widget, polling

I use  yii2-poll-widget on my page. 
I installed it:

```
php composer.phar require "pollext/poll":"dev-master"
```

And write on my page:

```
<?php
use pollext\poll\Poll;?>
<?php
        echo Poll::widget([
            'pollName'=>'Do you like PHP?',
            'answerOptions'=>
                [
                    'Yes',
                    'No',
                ],
        ]);
    ?>
```

But I get error:
**Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: pollext\poll\Poll::pollStatus**

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Hi. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.

Answer (score 1):

I **do not** recommend [pollext/poll](https://github.com/Dzhus111/pollext) because it contains multiple errors in its core code, like missing `)` or `undefined index`. We (I and 2 more people) tried to fix errors in its core files by hand *(I know we shouldn't do that as it's a widget, sitting in vendor directory but at least we could see if it works at all)*.

You can try to use this code below *(what we added/modified is not much, we did more to improve design and functionality but still wasn't good enough, not worth to continue)*:

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    use pollext\poll\AjaxSubmitButton;
    use yii\helpers\Url;
?>

<style>
    .poll{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background: #ffffff;
    }

    .poll label{
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        color: #464646;
    }

    .poll label:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .poll button[type="submit"]{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10pt;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #4682B4;
    }

    .poll-option-name{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: #464646;
    }
    .per_container{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: #464646;
        padding: 0; 
        margin: 0;
        max-width: 50px;
    }

    .support_forms button[type="submit"]{
        border: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #4682B4;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #ffffff;

    }
    .support_forms button[type="submit"]:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .support_forms button[type="submit"]:focus{
        outline: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .support_forms{
        margin-top: 0;
    }

</style>
<div class="poll" style="width:<?php echo $params['maxLineWidth']+55;?>px;" >
<?php  echo "<div style=\"max-width:".$params['maxLineWidth']."px; word-wrap: break-word; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold;\">".$pollData['poll_name']."</div>";?>
<?php $pullName = (isset($_POST['nameOfPoll'])) ? $_POST['nameOfPoll'] : '';?>
<?php if((Yii::$app->user->getId()==null && $_POST['pollStatus']!='show' && $isVote == false ) || ($pullName==$pollData['poll_name'] && $_POST['pollStatus']=='vote'&& $_POST['pollStatus']!='show' && Yii::$app->user->getId()==null)){
    echo "Sign in to vote";
}?>
    <?php if(($isVote == false && Yii::$app->user->getId()!=null && !empty($_POST['pollStatus']) && $_POST['pollStatus'] !='show') || ($pullName==$pollData['poll_name'] && $_POST['pollStatus']=='vote'&& $_POST['pollStatus']!='show' && Yii::$app->user->getId()!=null)){?>

                <?php echo Html::beginForm('#', 'post', ['class'=>'uk-width-medium-1-1 uk-form uk-form-horizontal']); ?>

                <?php echo Html::activeRadioList($model,'voice',$answers); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="poll_name" value="<?=$pollData['poll_name']?>"/>
                <?php AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
                    'label' => 'Vote',
                    'ajaxOptions' => [
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'url'=>'#',
                        'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(data){
                            $("body").html(data);
                            }'),
                    ],
                    'options' => ['class' => 'customclass', 'type' => 'submit'],
                    ]);
                    AjaxSubmitButton::end();
                ?>


                <?php echo Html::endForm(); 
            }

    ?>
    <?php if (($isVote == false && !empty($_POST['pollStatus']) && $_POST['pollStatus'] !='show') || (Yii::$app->user->getId()==null && $_POST['pollStatus']!='show') || ($pullName==$pollData['poll_name'] && $_POST['pollStatus']=='vote'&& $_POST['pollStatus']!='show')){?>
   <form method="POST" action="" class="support_forms">
   <input type="hidden" name="nameOfPoll" value="<?=$pollData['poll_name']?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="pollStatus" value="show"/>
     <?php AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
                    'label' => 'Show results',
                    'ajaxOptions' => [
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'url'=>'#',
                        'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(data){
                            $("body").html(data);
                            }'),
                    ],
                    'options' => ['class' => 'customclass', 'type' => 'submit'],
                    ]);
                    AjaxSubmitButton::end();
                ?>
   </form>
    <?php }?>
    <?php if($isVote == true || ($pullName==$pollData['poll_name'] && $_POST['pollStatus']=='show') ){?> 
        <?php 
            for($i = 0; $i<count($answersData); $i++){ 
                $voicesPer = 0;
                if($sumOfVoices ==0){
                    $voicesPer = 0;
                }else{
                    $voicesPer = round($answersData[$i]['value']/$sumOfVoices, 4);
                }

                $lineWidth = $params['maxLineWidth']*$voicesPer;     
        ?>

            <div class="single-line" style="margin-bottom: 10px; ">
                <?php echo "<div class=\"poll-option-name\">".$answersData[$i]['answers'].": ".$answersData[$i]['value']."</div>"; ?>
                <div  style="width: <?php echo $params['maxLineWidth']; ?>px;  height: <?php echo $params['linesHeight']; ?>px; background-color: <?php echo $params['backgroundLinesColor']; ?>; ">
                    <div style="width: <?php echo $lineWidth;?>px; height: <?php echo $params['linesHeight'] ?>px; background-color: <?php echo $params['linesColor']; ?>;">
                    <div class="per_container" style="display: block; line-height:<?php echo $params['linesHeight'] ?>px;  height: <?php echo $params['linesHeight'] ?>px;  
                    position: relative; left:<?php echo $params['maxLineWidth']+5; ?>px; margin: 0;"><?php echo ($voicesPer*100)."%"?></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }?>
    <?php }?>
    <?php if ($isVote == false && !empty($_POST['pollStatus']) && $_POST['pollStatus'] == 'show'){?>
    <form method="POST" action="" class="support_forms" style="margin-top: -10px;">
   <input type="hidden" name="nameOfPoll" value="<?=$pollData['poll_name']?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="pollStatus" value="vote"/>
     <?php AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
                    'label' => 'Vote',
                    'ajaxOptions' => [
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'url'=>'#',
                        'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(data){
                            $("body").html(data);
                            }'),
                    ],
                    'options' => ['class' => 'customclass', 'type' => 'submit'],
                    ]);
                    AjaxSubmitButton::end();
                ?>
     <?php }?>
   </form>
</div>
```

This modified come is taken from [pollext/views/index.php](https://github.com/Dzhus111/pollext/blob/master/views/index.php) file. In case you're wondering how it looks like:

[image]

Upper is a view for a person who didn't vote yet and below is a view for a person who have already voted.